Styles defined in <FRAME> affect parent page
I asked Gemini about styles defined in a <FRAME> element and the answer was quite clear that they are isolated from the parent page, answer here.
However, I did a simple test and a class defined inside a <FRAME> takes precedence, even in the parent page.


<style>
  .x { font-family: "Arial"; color: blue}
</style>
<div class="x" style="border: solid 1px blue">
  TEST - should be Arial and blue
</div>

<frame>
  <style>
    .x { font-family: "Garamond"; color:red}
  </style>
 <div class="x" style="border: solid 1px red">
   TEST - Garamond and red 
 </div>
  
</frame>



What have I done wrong? Is it possible to isolate styles, including stylesheets, in a <FRAME> element?

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame - and pay attention to the red box at the top. "AI" has led you astray. <frame> tags have an src referencing another file (which will indeed be isolated), not a body.

Thanks. What is an alternative to have two distinct sections in a page? I need to show a preview of a generated bulletin on the same page. Should I use <IFRAME>?

@OldGeezer you can use iframe but then the preview needs to be rendered in a separate url. If you want to keep them inside the same url, I think you can use @scope it basically lets you encapsulate your styles so they only apply to certain parts (a div for example). You can read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@scope

The closest you can do is to use an iframe with a srcdoc attribute, like this:


iframe {
  display:block;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
}
<style>
  .x { font-family: "Arial"; color: blue}
</style>
<div class="x" style="border: solid 1px blue">
  TEST - should be Arial and blue
</div>

<iframe srcdoc='
  <style>
    body { margin: 0 }
    .x { font-family: "Garamond"; color:red}
  </style>
 <div class="x" style="border: solid 1px red">
   TEST - Garamond and red 
 </div>'>
</iframe>



